# Get just the hash from SHA256.hash(data:)?

Tags: swift, generics, hash, sha256, sha

I'm trying to get just a hash from `SHA256.hash(data:)` but in order to do this I need to grab the description and then use `.replacingOccurrences(of: "SHA256 digest: ", with: "")`. Is there a way that I can just get the full SHA256 hash as a string?

```
func getId<T>(input: T) -> String {
    let input = "\(input)".utf8
    let data = Data(input)
        
    let hash = SHA256.hash(data: data).description.replacingOccurrences(of: "SHA256 digest: ", with: "")
        
    return hash
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply map `SHA256Digest` bytes into an hexa string:

```
import CryptoKit

extension UnsignedInteger where Self: CVarArg {
    var hexa: String { .init(format: "%ll*0x", bitWidth / 4, self) }
}
```

---

```
extension DataProtocol {
    var sha256Digest: SHA256Digest { SHA256.hash(data: self) }
    var sha256Data: Data { .init(sha256Digest) }
    var sha256Hexa: String { sha256Digest.map(\.hexa).joined() }
}
```

---

```
func getId<D: DataProtocol>(data: D) -> String {
    data.sha256Hexa
}
```

Comment: Hardly "simply" IMHO. Annoying there's no `.stringValue` or such. Now *that* would be simple.

Comment: Great solution! just to elaborate - because SHA256Digest has no member 'hexa', you can do:
var sha256Hexa: String { sha256Digest.map { byte in String(format: "%02x", byte) }.joined() }

Comment: @Tomer well I am not sure how you get this error since map should be applied to the `SHA256Digest.Element` not the collection. Make sure to add the generic hexa `UnsignedInteger` extension to your project. It works with all unsigned integer types including bytes `UInt8`

Comment: @LeoDabus Your are correct! sorry about it, I missed the extension. Your solution is working. Thanks!